# Load same DLL from Borland and Microsoft binaries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, c++builder, borland-c++

I have a case that seems very similar to [Executable loads same dll as already loaded dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364573/executable-loads-same-dll-as-already-loaded-dll).  Unfortunately the answer given there was not very informative, and anyway my case is somewhat more involved.  I have a Borland C++ Builder executable that loads up a business logic DLL, say BL.DLL.  Both the EXE and BL.DLL dynamically load a second DLL, say COM.DLL.  From what I gather, if the EXE and BL.DLL were to both `LoadLibrary` COM.DLL, the second load would not have any effect since both loads would occur in the same process.  But I imagine that if the first `LoadLibrary` were to occur using Borland-style dynamic linkage, it would not be aware of a Microsoft-style linkage of the same DLL even if in the same process.

So then, if I Borland-load BL.DLL and COM.DLL from the Borland EXE, and then Microsoft-load COM.DLL from aforementioned BL.DLL, do I end up with two separate instances in memory of COM.DLL?  For example, if I have a class inside COM.DLL, would the class's static variables be identically present to both BL.DLL and the EXE?

Comment: read the accepted answer of the referenced question. That says it all !

Comment: It doesn't matter how or how many times you load a dll ,implicitly (by linking) or explicitly (by load Library) ,it will be loaded only once in your application.

Comment: It does not say much, and is talking about DLL and EXE both loading the second DLL from a Microsoft environment.

Comment: it says it precisely ,nothing too much or too less.

Comment: I agree with @engf-010. no matter what, only one instance of the 2nd DLL will be loaded. If you run your code in debug mode inside the **C++ Builder** IDE, you cam open Module view ( Ctrl + Alt + M) which shows all the DLLs loaded and the address at which they have been loaded into. There will only be one instance of any DLL.

Comment: despite all Borland exists in the Windows eco system loading "normal" DLLs so a "Borland style dynamic linkage" seems a bit farfetched. All DLLs should follow the same rules otherwise you end up with a DLL that is more or less useless since the whole idea with DLLs is to share code.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.  I would appreciate it if someone were to kindly provide some source material in an answer so I can accept something with authoritative backing.